# Displaying JSON from an API in and HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I realize there is likely something very easy I'm missing here.  Also, I'm very new to php so please keep that in mind when responding :)

I am trying to display the results from an API call in an html table.  Here is my code:

```
// construct the query with our apikey and the query we want to make
$endpoint = 'http://www.coinmine.pw/api.php?method=coinprofit';
// setup curl to make a call to the endpoint
$session = curl_init($endpoint);
// indicates that we want the response back
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// exec curl and get the data back
$data = curl_exec($session);
// remember to close the curl session once we are finished retrieveing the data
curl_close($session);
// decode the json data to make it easier to parse the php
$search_results = json_decode($data, true);
if ($search_results === NULL) die('Error parsing json');
//print_r($search_results);

echo '<table>';
foreach ($search_results as $coin) {

$name = $coin["name"];
$profit = $coin["profit"];

echo '<tr><td>' . $name . '</tr></td>';
echo '<tr><td>' . $profit . '</tr></td>';

}
echo '</table>';
```

All the above outputs is name profit name profit name profit but with no separate table rows.

Ideally I'd like the whole api call to be in a table, but I'm just trying to get this to display properly first so I can figure out making the whole table.

Bonus points if someone can point me in the right direction to make the table sortable by each column.

Comment: `echo '<tr><td>' . $name . '</tr></td>';` & `echo '<tr><td>' . $profit . '</tr></td>';`

should be

`echo '<tr><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>';` & `echo '<tr><td>' . $profit . '</td></tr>';`

Comment: For bonus points: [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) is a neat tool to make sortable tables by column. It uses some javascript, but very easy to setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing your `<tr>` before closing the child `<td>`. Should be:

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>' . $profit . '</td></tr>';
```

But it looks like you want each `$coin` to be its own row, in which case it should be:

```
echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$profit.'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: I can't believe I did that lol.  New to php, not to html :)  It still didn't fix the issue though.  It is displaying the same way.

Comment: Do you want a row for each `$coin`? You shouldn't wrap both `$name` and `$profit` in their own `<tr>` then, you should have two `<td>`s wrapped in one `<tr>`. Updated my answer.

Comment: That is indeed what I'm trying to do.  However, since I couldn't get it to display right I thought I would just break it down as much as possible and see if i could get ANYTHING to show up in different rows.  Here's exactly what the output is looking like with your code above http://altcoinfo.com/mining-info/

Comment: It seems like maybe my code is right but there's something in the data that isn't allowing me to do what I want?

Comment: I don't even see a table in there - do you have something that strips out HTML tags in your output?

Comment: Yeah I didn't see the html table either.  I'll take a look around but I don't see how that could be.  It's just a standard wordpress page.

Comment: Be sure you added the HTML in the code editor and not in the WYSIWYG part.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked that and I did.  I am using a plugin that allows php so it could be something funky with that.  I tried just adding a super simple table using echo and it is stripping away the table elements of that as well.

Comment: Definitely an issue with your setup then. The code is fine.

Comment: Yep, I just deleted that plugin and found a different one that executes php and it worked fine.  Thank you so very much for your help figuring this out.  I really appreciate it.